# How to choose automatic preferred resolution in Xorg-server

Tags: xorg

I am building a Linux Live-Distro.

My xorg.conf looks like this:

```
Section "Monitor"

    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    Option       "dpms" "off"
    Option       "dpms" "false"
    DisplaySize             349 196

    #does NOT work
    PreferredMode "1360x768"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

    Identifier  "Screen0"
    Device  "Card0"
    Monitor "Monitor0"
    DefaultColorDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth   24
        Modes "1360x768" "1280x720" "1024x768" "800x600"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

so if I plug in a (Test-)Full-HD TV every times it uses **1920x1080**. When changing

```
Modes "1360x768" "1280x720" "1024x768" "800x600"
```

into

```
Modes "1280x720" "1360x768" "1024x768" "800x600"
```

the TV uses 1280x720.

Is it possible to force switching the modes, as defined in "Screen"-section?

My idea is the xorg-server tries to switch into "1360x768", if not working switch to "1280x720", after that 1024x768 and so on (as defined in xorg.conf).

Bets regards

Comment: Why ship an xorg.conf with a static list of modes instead of just leaving it out and letting Xorg autoconfigure?

Answer (score 1):

Modern Xorg doesn't require a xorg.conf at all. I autodetects all connected hardware (display devices, screens, input devices) and configures apropriately at runtime. Even hotplugging is supported.